# Landing page keeps returning static files in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to use static files in my project, but when the user makes a get request to my "/" landing page. I want to send non-static things like a json. But for some reason it just automatically sends my index.html in my static file.

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.use(express.static("public"));

app.get("/", (req, res) => {   //This sends the user to the index.html even tho i want to send 123
  res.send("123");
});

app.listen("3000");
```

Comment: You can specify a base url like `app.use("/baseurl",express.static("public"))`, so that it will serve static pages only if url starts with `baseurl`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your code is written, the `express.static()` middleware looks at the `/` request, finds an `index.html` file in the public directory and serves that as the response for the `/` request.  This is a feature of `express.static()` that is causing a conflict for you with your custom route for `"/"`.

You have at least four choices for a solution here:

1. You can specify an option for `express.static()` to disable the `index.html` feature so it will avoid the `"/"` route and pass control on to your subsequent route handlers.
2. You can move the `express.static()` middleware AFTER your `app.get("/", ...)` route so that your custom route gets first dibs at the request.
3. You can remove the `index.html` file from your public directory so `express.static()` won't find it.  Using a template system for all your HTML files that locates all HTML template files in some other directory that `express.static()` can't see (such as a `views` directory) would cause this to happen too or just moving it to some private directory and using it from your code from the private directory would work too.
4. Give ALL your static resources a common path prefix so there is never a URL conflict between static resources and custom route handlers.

---

The first option (disable index.html feature in `express.static()`) would look like this:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

// disable index.html feature
app.use(express.static("public"), {index: false});

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("123");
});

app.listen("3000");
```

The second option (change the order of route definitions/middleware) would look like this:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("123");
});

// put this after custom route definitions so they take precendence
app.use(express.static("public"));

app.listen("3000");
```

The fourth option (give all static resources a common path prefix) would look like this:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.use(express.static("/static", "public"));

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("123");
});

app.listen("3000");
```

With this fourth option, you'd then have to prefix all your static URLs with the static prefix (which you can make anything you want) and thus `"/"` would never be a match for `express.static()`.

Comment: A comment above gave me an idea of using ejs under the views folders instead of regular html. I guess that is a solution, but is it escaping from the real answer? lol

Comment: @VehbiKaraağaç - Please see the additional options and examples I've added to my answer.  I'm not sure that using any template system and the views folder actually addresses the root problem you asked about.  There could still be a conflict between `express.static()` and custom routes (even custom routes using ejs) unless you stopped using `express.static()` entirely.  Anyway, I hope this explains how the issue occurs and you can choose one of these methods to stay with your current design, yet fix the problem or of course, you could go with a different design entirely.

Comment: Using a separate directory for your ejs is the correct answer. Otherwise you are serving the ejs files along with your static assets. Are you rendering your ejs from the same public folder?

Comment: @NathanFries - If `express.static()` and custom routes are using the same path prefix, then the problem can still occur even if using a views folder.  So, that all by itself isn't how you avoid this problem.  One needs to make sure that your `express.static()` statement is either defined after the custom routes or does not conflict with custom routes (of which I offerred a number of ways to do that).

Comment: There is no conflict. The views folder is never served. It is used to contain the ejs or html files that will be served by the route by either res.send() or res.render()

Comment: @NathanFries - If there's an `index.html` file in the public directory that `express.static()` reads from and the route order remains as it is in the question, then there's still a conflict no matter where the views folder is.  If you're saying that the views solution just happens to remove the `index.html` file from the `public` directory so `express.static()` will now ignore the `"/"` route, I'll agree that would solve it too, but that's almost a side effect that happens to work rather than a full understanding of the problem.

Comment: @NathanFries - And, an accidental introduction of one `index.html` file into the `public` directory could break things again.  I think it's much better to implement options 1,2 or 4 in my answer so you have an unbreakable solution.  Did you really downvote this answer that fully explains what's going on and what the options are?

Comment: That's a stretch. I don't downvote if I am providing comment.

Comment: My point is that an accidental introduction *would* break things again, but accidental introduction of an index.html file to the public directory makes as much sense as *accidentally* moving the express.static() middleware to before the route. Your solutions are perfectly valid, as is simply moving the html file (probably temporary anyways since he is using ejs)

Comment: @NathanFries - So, you're advocating for my option 3 I guess which happens to be a side effect of using a template system that is served from a different directory (and thus gets rid of index.html from that public directory).  OK. I thought I'd explain what is really going on here and offer a number of options so the OP can fully understand what's happening and make sure they avoid the problem in the future.

Comment: @NathanFries - And, route definition order is often important in Express, particularly with middleware.  It's not something to ever be taken lightly so any change in route order should always be thoughful.  Similarly what you put in a `public` folder served by `express.static()` must always be thoughtful too since it's served by default and automatically.  The OP is free to choose any of the options I've described or take the learnings and devise their own solution, whichever works best for them.

Comment: @NathanFries - FYI, no explanation for why an `index.html` file is in view of `express.static()` in the first place is described in the question.  I assume that maybe they wanted a `/index.html` route to be served automatically by `express.static()`.  If that was the case, they would need to do something more than just switch to a view system for their custom routes.

Comment: I don't think they are mutually exclusive. My original intent was to be clear that any template files should not be in the static directory, and the html should be served by res.sendFile or res.render from an appropriate folder. I made a deduction that an index.html file was present in the public directory, which was validated

Comment: @NathanFries - You seem to be assuming that one can never use a template system for some HTML files and also have some static HTML files.  There's no rule that says that is always the case.  Anyway, I think we understand each other.  Your are advocating that `index.html` should not be in the public directory and that is one of the options I suggest.

Comment: I think we are on the same page. I *am* making the statement that if static HTML files are used, they should be served by a route, instead of being accessible by going to `/public/about.html` for example

Comment: @NathanFries - Hmmm, you lost me there.  I disagree that all static HTML files must be served by a custom route and you should never use `express.static()` for a static HTML file.  As long as you lay out the code and URLs properly, it's perfectly fine to use `express.static()` for static HTML files.  It works just as well for them as it does for other static resources.  I think we've drifted off topic here so I'll sign off now from this side discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any particular reason that you have an index.html file inside your `public` directory and are serving something else? The convention is serve static assets such as CSS, JS, images etc. from your `public` folder, and HTML / templates in folder which would be a sibling of `public` such as `views`.

The browser will always default to rendering an index.html file if it is found in the root of the public directory. Move the HTML file to a separate folder and the route should work

Comment: So maybe I should just use EJS and do my htmls under the views?

Answer (score 0):

app.use is a middleware, so whenever you're running a app, it always first go through the middleware, Try the below code

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.get("/", (req, res) => {   //This sends the user to the index.html even tho i want to send 123
  res.send("123");
});

app.use(express.static("public"));

app.listen("3000");
```